# Accessing Application Server directly by public IP in citrix Farm

Tags: vpn, citrix

I have an citrix application server in SiteB and I have a Farm in SiteA. We want to add this server into that Farm in SiteB, and access it from the internet via web interface. SiteA and SiteB are connected via VPN.

But we would like to do that in a way the ICA traffic goes directly to the application server public IP (behind NAT) in siteB without using siteA and the VPN to route this traffic. Do you know if this is posible? Maybe there is a way to change the host in the ica file for this server in the webinterface (without editing manually each time)?

We are using Citrix 4.5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i have the solution you're asking for but there is an option to create another ICA Listener on a specific Network Interface Card,
You could try creating a one that listens only from that NAT connected NIC,
Here is the article that explains this:
http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX115152

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the server's public IP to the server using ALTADDR (google CTX039746), then change the web interface setting to use external IPs (Can't remember the setting name off the top of my head).